# Max theoretical powerline bandwidth using more than 2 devices and recommended speed for 1 Gbps network ports

Tags: networking, bandwidth, powerline-networking

I'd like to set up a powerline based network on a 3 storey home. I'd like it to be as reliable and as fast as possible. My network equipment has 1 Gbps ports. I see that some powerline products can go up to a theoretical speed of 2.4 Gbps. I guess it'd be a waste of resources since my ports are all 1Gbps however... how is the overall bandwidth affected if I deploy more than 2 powerline adapters? And what is the most suitable powerline bandwidth to not waste resources knowing that my network ethernet ports are all 1 Gbps?

- 2 x 2.4 Gbps powerline adaptors - 2.4 Gbps max "theoretical" bandwidth
- 3 x 2.4 Gbps powerline adaptors - max "theoretical" bandwidth? Would it be 2.4/2?
- 4 x 2.4 Gbps powerline adaptors - max "theoretical" bandwidth? Would it be 2.4/3?
- ...

Comment: Many powerline adapters need to be on the same electric circuit for best / any results. That seems unlikely between floors.  Any way to string Ethernet?  That is what I have done.

Comment: I am aware of any Powerline adapters that support more than a pair of devices. When you introduce multiple pairs you have to put them on multiple circuits.

Comment: My understanding is that you can get this powerline https://www.devolo.co.uk/magic-2-lan-triple with 3 adapters (and also each of them has 3 LAN ports)

Comment: @Ramhound your comment confuses me.  Are you saying you can only have 2 powerline adapters?  As that is not true.  You can have as many as you want, in theory.  I have had as many as 8 powerline adapters connected to devices in my old home at one point.

Comment: @Keltari and how is the bandwidth affected? Any changes in having 2 vs 3 vs 8 connected?

Comment: @Unai Its been years since I used powerline networking.  I never noticed any issues running multiple adapters.  However, I never measured bandwidth, as I never had a reason too.

Comment: @Unai I believe the speed is more affected by the quality of the wiring than anything else in a home.  Ive know other people in the past with powerline networking in multiple floors as well and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Powerline adaptors suffer a similar set of limitations and problems as Wifi. You don't have a problem with objects blocking signals (except for them potentially being on different circuits) or range, but there are similarities.

- That "2.4Gbps" is also very likely to be a "best case" laboratory data rate using transmission in only one direction. That leads into the next point.
- There is only one effective "wire" that data is transmitted on, and communications is by necessity only going to be half duplex. What that means is that unlike Ethernet, where multiple input and output wires are used, a device on Powerline can **only** be transmitting **or** receiving, not both at the same time.
- That half-duplex nature means that if two devices are sharing lots of data at the same time then, at best, each device will only be able to use the line for half the time.  Normally though that can be fine. For things like internet use you are mostly transferring data in one direction with occasional small replies asking for more data. This limitation is mainly something to be aware of when constructing larger networks where multiple devices are all sending and receiving at the same time. How much this affects you depends on your use case. If Wifi was mostly fine, then powerline will also be mostly fine.
- As only one device can be transmitting at a time other devices have to wait their turn. They must listen for communications on the wire and wait for everyone else to "shut up" before they can transmit. One thing that can happen is if one device pauses and another goes to transmit at the same time they will "collide" on the wire. There needs to be some detection of this and each device has to back off and retry some slightly random amount of time later. This collision, detection and pause causes a period of time where there is no "good" data on the line and it is effectively wasted bandwidth.  You can read up more on this at [Carrier-sense multiple access at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection)
- You are subject to noise from all other devices using the wires. Home electrical appliances all emit various kinds of noise both as radio waves and as noise on their power lines. A poorly shielded microwave can induce frequencies in wires, computer power supplies switch at high frequencies and can cause noise on their supplies. There are lots of sources of RF and conducted noise on power lines which make it difficult to say precisely what effect it will have on the signals you are also trying to put on the power line.

Ironically the heavier your use of the network with multiple devices all using the same wire, the slower that network will be.

All of these combine to make it difficult to say what bandwidth any one device will get.

For these reasons I would put a wet finger in the air and guess that between two devices you will mostly get the advertised speed minus anywhere from 10-40% to account for local noise and problems, for more devices you will *maybe* get something similar, but it will depend on what those devices are doing exactly.

For "normal" use you should get somewhere close to the advertised speeds, but bear in mind that all devices will be sharing that advertised speed.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if everything was 'perfect' the rated speed works roughly like a bus, and is shared amongst all the devices in the network. Its 'half' duplex, so practically 2.4 gigabit is basically gigabit each way with some bandwidth to spare.

*Practically* - with just 2 nodes, I've at best gotten 1/2 to 1/3 the overall rated speed, presumably due to the quality of the *wiring*. I've also had, in the past had interference from a dryer which resulted in cut outs. Every device that runs a SMPS, has a mains powered motor and otherwise injects noise into the mains is going to affect your maximum throughput.

Newer powerline standards tend to be better about dealing with noise, and that's the real benefit here.

You're also *rarely* going to hit full gigabit even with a fully cabled connection short of local file transfers. 4k video streaming will fit neatly into 10Mbps or even fast ethernet.